# what is the difference between if and [[ in bash?

Tags: bash

I see that

```
if cmd
then
echo Hi
fi
```

works differently from

```
if [[ $(cmd) ]]
then
echo Hi
fi
```

So what happens when there is a [[ and when there is not?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the shell `[` is an alias for the test command. It *is* the command. The `[[` is a feature of some shells that is only slightly different. In bash it is a keyword, rather than a command, but functions like a command.

You can think of it this way: you are running `[[` and providing the output of "$(cmd)" as arguments to that command. `if` then checks the return status of `[[`. When no operators are given to `[[`, `-n` is implied.

```
   -n string
          True if the length of string is non-zero.
```

For your examples:

```
if cmd          # check the return status of cmd
if [[ $(cmd) ]] # check if cmd has any output
```

Comment: Your last two lines of the post nails the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

An `if expr` statement (without brackets) checks the return status of `expr` after it's evaluated as a bash command. Upon success, it is treated as a `true` value.

On the other hand, `if [[ expr ]]` with double square brackets is a `bash`-specific *keyword* that can handle its own set of options, such as `-f /path/to/file` to test for file existence, or even handle variable tests such as `$a == $b`. Within these brackets, you have to explicitly tell it to evaluate some expression as a set of bash commands with `if [[ $(cmds) ]]`. Otherwise, it will treat anything there as a special expression and will be parsed differently.

There's also the `if [ expr ]` construct, which is generally an alias (or, in some cases, an approximative implementation of) `if test expr`. If the `test` command has an option available to use, then you can also use it between single brackets.

For more fun, there's the `if ((expr))` construct, which is best when dealing with numbers, since everything inside is evaluated as an arithmetic expression. This is also a keyword, like the double brackets.

Basically, `if expr` and `if [ expr ]` are portable (i.e. all shells can handle them, and handle them pretty much identically) and `if [[ expr ]]` and `if (( expr ))` are implementation-specific, i.e. they are keywords whose evaluation depend highly on the shell you're using them in (and if you're not using something like `bash`, `zsh`, or `ksh`, they might not even exist).

Comment: One thing that to note that `[[`, `[`, and `(( ))` can all be used outside of conditionals (although it only makes sense for `(( ))`).

Comment: Well, you can also use `[[` outside conditionals for more succinct syntax, like `[[ expr ]] && expr_is_true_cmds || expr_is_false_cmds`. But that's not as readable, ofc.